# How to Disable "Save Password for this website" Selenium Python Syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, popup

I want to disable this pop up with selenium in Python.
[popup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47pM9.png)

I have seen a lot of answers that show how to do this in java but I am having a hard time implementing it in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Python** implementation for the task you want to accomplish using selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
    'credentials_enable_service': False,
    'profile': {
        'password_manager_enabled': False
    }
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```